# Why is my import statement looking for '.\src\components\Form\Components'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, components, filepath

Full error code is:

Cannot find file: 'Form.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\Form\Components'.

Attached is a screenshot of my folder setup and App.js file [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with file or folder name with its uppercase and lower case, here you need to change `'.\src\components\Form\Components'` to `'.\src\Components\Form\Form'` also need to change `'.\src\Components\Posts\Posts'`.